# Division using repeated subtraction in MARIE

Tags: assembly, marie

I am trying to write a program in the MARIE assembly language that will divide two numbers using repeated subtraction. I need to count the number of subtractions needed before reaching zero or minus numbers. I am having a few problems with this, here is my code so far:

```
    Load    A
    Store   A

Load,   Load    A 
    Subt    B
    Skipcond 800
    Jump    Endloop


    Load    C
    Add     One
    Store   C

Endloop,    Output
    Halt

A,  DEC     10
B,  DEC     2
C,  DEC     0
One, DEC    1
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been struggling with this for a while

UPDATE:

I have changed my code but now get an infinite loop - any ideas how I can fix this?

```
    Input
    Store   A
    Input
    Store   B
    Load    A
    Skipcond    800
    Jump    Endloop
Loop,   Subt    B
    Store   A
    Load    X
    Add     One
    Store   X
    Load    A
    Skipcond    400
    Jump    Loop
    Load    X
Endloop,    Halt
A,  DEC         0
B,  DEC         0
X,  DEC         0
One, DEC        1
```

Comment: I don't see you looping back. Other than that, it looks kinda sensible. You will want to output `C` of course.

Comment: I have changed my code but now get an infinite loop - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Skipcond    400` if the number is not divisible by the divider
 there will be an endless loop as it will go negative not zero.

Care needs to be taken not to increment X when the remainder is not divisible by B. So a check is made for the remainder equalling zero, so X can be incremented when A is no longer positive.

```
    Input
    Store   A
    Input
    Store   B

Loop,   Load    A  
    Subt    B
    Store   A
    Skipcond 800
    Jump    Endloop / While X is positive it will continue
    Load    X
    Add     One
    Store   X
    Jump Loop

IncrementX, Load    X
    Add     One
    Store   X
    Load    A
    Subt    B
    Store   A

Endloop, Load   A
    Skipcond 000 /Skip if negative
    Jump    IncrementX

    Load    X
    Output   
    Halt
A,  DEC     0
B,  DEC     0
X,  DEC     0
One, DEC    1
```